# Adding extended class to multimap

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a multimap as follows:

```
Multimap<String, ? extends A> order = LinkedListMultimap.create();
B b = new B();
order.put("key", b); // shows error
```

where `B` is

```
class B extends A {}
```

The error is as follows:

> The method `put(String, capture#2-of ? extends A)` in the type `Multimap<String,capture#2-of ? extends A>` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, B)`.

I should be able to add a `B` since `B` extends `A`. But I am not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *mean* a multimap from `String` to objects of type `A` or any subtype of `A`, then that's a `Multimap<String, A>`.  If you mean a multimap from `String` to objects of some *specific but unknown* subtype of `A`, then that's a `Multimap<String, ? extends A>`.

Comment: so for example if C also extends A and I want to add both B as well as C to the multimap. In order to get that should I not configure the Multimap as ? extends A??

Comment: No, you shouldn't; in that case you _really do_ want `Multimap<String, A>`.

Comment: A `Multimap<String, ? extends A>` means that there is some specific type `X` that extends `A`, and the `Multimap` is actually a `Multimap<String, X>`, but you don't know what `X` is.  You can't put _any_ value except `null` into a `Multimap<String, ? extends A>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add values to **order**, because they key is

```
? extends A
```

and compiler doesn't know the lower bound type.